# 406 (Inacceptable) error with ajax and spring mvc not maven

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm trying to run an ajax method with spring MVC, but I'm getting the error 406: "406 (Inacceptable)"

Spring MVC with tiles, Dynamic Web Project

Help me config servlet.xml

Controller:

```
@RestController

public class JsonController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/car", method = RequestMethod.POST,headers= "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody Car load(@ModelAttribute(value="test") String test){

        Car car = new Car();
        car.setColor("Blue");
        car.setMiles(100);
        car.setVIN("1234");

        return car;
    }
```

}

View :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        url: "car.html", 
        data: {
    test: "datatest"
},
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (data) { 
           alert(data);
           console.log(data);
        }
    });

});

</script>
```

servlet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">


    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="controller" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass">
            <value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>


</beans>
```

Please, anyone have any solutions ?

Thanks anyone!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
url: "/car", 
data: "taiKhoan: data",
```

"=" operator is not valid in jquery here and your url does not match probably.

Answer (score 0):

Add MediaType to controller method RequestMapping

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/car", method = RequestMethod.POST,  headers = {"content-type=application/json"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax call has an error in the data element:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: "car.html", 
    data: {
        test: "SomeOtherValueThanDataBecauseOtherwiseItsConfusing"
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) { 
       alert(data);
       console.log(data);
    }
});
```